# Mutate a slice passed as an argument to a function in Go

Tags: go, slice

I wrote some code where a function `f` takes a slice `s` as an argument and modifies it without returning it.

Since slices can be considered as references to underlying arrays, I thought that the slice would be actually modified outside of that function's scope, but it's not the case.

An example would be the code below (https://play.golang.org/p/Y5JUmDtRXrz).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pop(s []int) int {
    first, s := s[0], s[1:]
    return first
}

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
    first := pop(s)
    fmt.Println(first, s)
}
```

`pop(s)` actually returns `0`, which is expected. But then in the output `s` still has `0` as its first element.

```
0 [0 1 2 3]

Program exited.
```

Why? And how could I solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two separate things are happening here, both of which prevent this from behaving as you expect:

```
func pop(s []int) int {
    first, s := s[0], s[1:]
```

The first (and simpler) issue is you're defining a new local variable `s` here, which shadows you function parameter `s`.

Second, slices do point to an underlying array, but the slice is still passed by copy, just like everything else. That means that:

```
s = s[1:]
```

Modifies *your copy of s* to have a different window on the underlying array. That doesn't change the slice in the caller. *However*, if you change *the values in the underlying array*, that *will* be reflected in the caller, e.g.:

```
s[1] = 42
```

You can learn more about this [throughout the Tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/8) and [on the Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added some `fmt.Printf("pointer: %p value: %p \n", &s, s)` before and after `s` is changed in the code. You're right, the pointer in the `pop` scope is different than the one in the `main` scope, which explains that slices are passed by value to functions.
However, the line `first, s := s[0], s[1:] doesn't create a new variable (`&s` has the same address). The `:=` is only necessary and meaningful for `first`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `first, s := s[0], s[1:]` creates a new variable `s` since you are using `:=`. On top of that if you want to modify the slice you need to pass it by pointer.

Passing it by value, it will refer to the same underlying array, but the slice itself is a copy. So changes to the underlying array would be reflected in `main`, but changes to the slice itself would not.

Here is an example of passing the slice by pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pop(s *[]int) int {
    first := (*s)[0]
    *s = (*s)[1:]
    return first
}

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
    first := pop(&s)
    fmt.Println(first, s)
}
```